# How to execute commands requiring root privileges inside a script?

Tags: bash, privileges, slide

I have to change the frequency of CPU (through slide privileges) . I have written the command to change frequencies inside a script .However , when I run the script, I get the following error message

```
 #!/bin/bash
slide
        for i in 0 1 2 3 
        do
                echo 1600000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu${i}/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
        done
```

when I run the script , it gives following error

```
./change_freq.sh: line 4: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Where to learn more about slide privileges?

Comment: slide is a command that gives partial root access . And it does not require password authentication , if the system administrator has given you slide privilege.. For the current problem, you can substitute, slide with sudo and consider the problem

Comment: Can you give a URL where information about the 'slide' program can be found?  Searching for 'slide' is rather hard - you get Powerpoint instead.

Comment: Even I cannot find information about that. But that command works on our lab machines. I don't know about it's mechanism and how it functions . But when I "slide",  I get partial root access. That is what my system admin told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how `slide` works, but a possibly similar action using `sudo` that produces the same kind of error would be:

```
sudo echo foo > /path/to/file
```

The way to solve that is:

```
echo foo | sudo tee /path/to/file > /dev/null
```

I would be curious to know if any of the following provide further information on the origin of `slide`:

```
type -a slide
man slide
slide -v
slide --version
slide -h
slide -?
```

Comment: I will ask my system admin about this and let you know further info. I tried all the above commands , but I got this "/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument"

Comment: @SharatChandra: Where did the `-c` come from? None of the commands in my answer include that. What does `file $(type -P slide)` give you?